# How do I enable logging or debug output for ImageResizer in C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, imageresizer

I'm using ImageResizer in C# app. Some of the functionality I want to use does not have an associated property in the Instructions object. The docs say, "Just because a key doesn't have a property wrapper doesn't mean you can't use it. i["key"] = value; isnt' that scary."

However, you can put any nonsense in the Instructions Dictionary and nothing will be reported. This means that if I've done something wrong I'm unlikely to notice my mistake.

How can I view log output that will tell me what ImageResizer is doing so I can catch my mistakes?

Roughly what I'm doing:

```
var instructions = new Instructions
{
    Mode = FitMode.Max,
};
instructions["fastscale"] = "true";
instructions["down.filter"] = "RobidouxSharp";

var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    var job = ImageBuilder.Current.Build(path, stream, instructions);
    stream.Position = 0;

    bitmapImage.BeginInit();
    bitmapImage.StreamSource = stream;
    bitmapImage.EndInit();
    bitmapImage.Freeze();
}
```

Comment: What is ImageResizer? Why are you using it, instead of e.g. a TransformedBitmap?

Comment: Since this is a commercial product with support, maybe the people who sold you this thing are in the best position to offer advice. What with writing the thing.

Comment: Indeed. In the past Nathaniel has been very responsive here. Any answer given on SO is easily found by others.

Comment: @Clemens - I will be comparing results to TransformedBitmap and scaling inside BitmapImage. Thus far, BitmapImage is unacceptably soft when downscaling large images (but fast). The trade-offs I care about are speed, quality, and the ability to sharpen.